# problems synchronizing gradle with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a laptop running Linux Mint which is offline mostly of the time. I've installed Android Studio 3.2.1, the JDK 1.8.0_101, Gradle 4.6-all and the Android-SDK 24.4.1. I downloaded and installed the SDK platform API 19 for Android 4.4.2.
Back into the Android Studio I went into `Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Gradle` and checked `Offline work`, also I hit `Use local gradle distribution` and Android Studio recognized by itself the Gradle installation folder.
Now when I go to `Build / Make project` it begins the building, but it shows me this error:

[image]

And the error log says:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6-all.
Required by:
project :
... 102 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6-all available for offline mode.
... 128 more
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.6-all'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

There is just one more thing I'd like to add: this is the very first time I use Android Studio. I've been googleing this for a while and always find the same answer: check offline work.

I went to a friend for help and he told me to remove the default layout. I can't tell what is the default layout.

My question is: how can I get this working offline? Do I need to use a different version of Gradle? What am I missing here?

Comment: I doubt this is Android Studio problem. The same error would show up on the project terminal after `./gradlew build`

Comment: @cricket_007, I'm asking because I have no idea on how to solve this

Comment: Hi, can you post you build.gradle file? This will show if there are any discrepancies  between version numbers

Comment: Could you please add your gradle files to the question?

Comment: @EamonScullion and @cricket_007, I edited my post with the contents of the `build.gradle` and `gradle-wrapper.properties` files.

Comment: Have you synced gradle at least once before setting offline mode? You need to let android studio download all of the dependencies once before you can start using offline mode

Comment: @EamonScullion, yes, Android Studio downloaded everything it needed.